# While writing into xlsx file not working using apache-poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to append data in 'xlsx' file but getting null pointer exception. I tried to solve issue using existed solutions but non of them worked for me.

Below is my code to write in xlsx file.

```
package test;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String excelFileName = "Y:\\RB and UCM Production Support\\RB\\RB Prod Support Knowledge Base\\UAR\\test.xlsx";//name of excel file

        String sheetName = "Sheet1";//name of sheet

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName) ;

        //XSSFRow r = sheet.createRow(0);

        //iterating r number of rows
        for (int r=0;r < 5; r++ )
        {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);

            //iterating c number of columns
            for (int c=0;c < 5; c++ )
            {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);

                cell.setCellValue("Cell "+r+" "+c);
                System.out.println("Cell "+r+" "+c);
            }
        }
//      wb.close();
//      String excelFileName1 = "Y:\\RB and UCM Production Support\\RB\\RB Prod Support Knowledge Base\\UAR\\test1.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);

        //write this workbook to an Outputstream.
        wb.write(fileOut);

        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();
        wb.close();
    }
}
```

Also I have added all the jar file into the project path.

[image: Project and jar file added]
Moreover, while executing the project a error pop up is coming up.
below is a screen shot for the same.

[image: Error]

Error faced while running above code.
[image: nullPointerException]

Please Help!!!!

Comment: The red exclamation mark on your project means that some of your build path entries are missing. Check them. Also, provide the full stack trace and tell us which line generates the exception.

Comment: You shouldn't even try running your code if it still has compilation errors. Open the problems view, and fix all the compilation errors listed there before even trying to run your code.

Comment: I ran the code. After running the code I am getting such error.

Comment: Again, you should NOT run your code. Not before you have fixed all the errors. If you know your car has a broken engine and only two wheels out of four, you shouldn't try to drive it. And if you try anyway, and then get into an accident, well, you deserved it. Fix the car first. Then drive it. Then if something is still not working, then ask.

Comment: Can you please suggest me some fixes..as I tried so many things but non of them working for me.

Comment: Well, you have the problems view in front of your eyes, listing all the errors to fix. We have nothing, son can't possibly guess what is wrong. Read the error messages. If you don't understand them, post them.

Comment: The problem was with 'poi-examples-3.17.jar'. When I removed it from build path everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a build issue or you're not using correct Poi.jar.

```
//Implementation org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(OutputStream)
public final void write(OutputStream stream) throws IOException {
    //force all children to commit their changes into the underlying OOXML Package
    Set<PackagePart> context = new HashSet<PackagePart>();
    onSave(context);
    context.clear();

    //save extended and custom properties
    getProperties().commit();

    getPackage().save(stream);
}
```

As per attached Error screenshot, an exception occurs `getProperties()`, which happens when POI jar is not getting underlying properties or unable to create properties in the absence of OPCPackage.

**Note:**
POI creates OPCPackage when you create an instance of `XSSFWorkbook()`

Refer: Javadoc of XSSFWorkbook() for more details:

To get a valid jar, use below link/ or use maven dependency:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.17